# Libgdx blending textures based on specific colors?

Tags: libgdx, sprite, tile, alphablending

To explain this problem in a simple way, imagine three 16x16 terrain tiles: one full sand, one full grass, and one transition of sand and grass.

After creating the map, I'd like to overlay a larger pattern onto these tiles so that they don't look so repetitive. My current solution, for example, is to have a large 64x64 repeating sand pattern, and every time I see a sand tile, I'll look at what row and column its in, and instead use a corresponding 16x16 chunk of the 64x64 tile. This way, the larger pattern is used overall and the sand looks nice (same for grass).

The problem comes with transition tiles, which may be half sand, half grass. I'd like to be able to overlay half of a transition tile with the sand pattern, and the other half with the grass pattern. Is there any way to declare half of a tile transparent and overlay something over it, and then declare the other half transparent and overlay something else on it? Obviously there needs to be two separate alpha channels - can it be blended on a specific pixel color basis? Meaning I declare some green pixel to be transparent for the grass sections and some yellow pixel to be transparent for the sand sections?

I don't know how to do this in libgdx, if it is even possible, so any code help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitly consider using shaders in libgdx.

If you use shaders, you can pass multiple textures to the fragmentshader at the same time: For example a grass, a sand and a b/w blending texture made/calculated for the correct blending. Your fragmentshader could decide which texture (grass or sand) is used for fragment-color calculation (or both).
Your fragmentshader code could look like this:

```
void main() {
    float alpha = texture2D(u_yourBlendingTexture, v_yourTerrainTexCoords);
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_yourGrassTexture, v_yourTerrainTexCoords) * alpha + texture2D(u_yourSandTexture, v_yourTerrainTexCoords) * (1.0 - alpha);
}
```

Alternative:

```
void main() {
    float alpha = texture2D(u_yourBlendingTexture, v_yourTerrainTexCoords);
    gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(u_yourGrassTexture, v_yourTerrainTexCoords), texture2D(u_yourSandTexture, v_yourTerrainTexCoords), alpha);
}
```

It's not very optimised, especially when you are binding multiple textures at the same time it could slow down your programm/app.